# How to change a class attribute inside __init__?

Tags: python, class, attributes

```
class Ant:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        if count == 0:
            self.real = True
        else:
            self.real = False
        count += 1
```

So basically what I want to achieve is I want only the first instance of this class to have the "real" attribute to be `True`, and the subsequent attributes to be `False`. I know right now this is going to give me unboundlocal error for `count`. How do I make this work?

Comment: `count` inside `__init__` is just a normal local variable. You need `Ant.count` to access the *class level variable*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change `count` To`Ant.count`

As `count` is a class member (shared between all instances of Ant class) and does not belong to a specific instance you should use it with the prefix of the class name.

```
class Ant:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        if Ant.count == 0:
            self.real = True
        else:
            self.real = False
        Ant.count += 1
```

Comment: `self.count` would also work and wouldn't require hardcoding the name of the class into the function (so it won't need to be fixed if the classname  was ever changed).

Comment: @martineau No, self.count would be an instance variable - that's very specifically _not_ what the OP wants. They want a class variable, so Ant.count is the (maybe only) correct way to reference it.

Comment: Oops, yes, you're correct. `self` only works for reading the class variable value, not for changing it, which would create an instance variable as a side-effect (and hide the class attribute thereafter). That said, it's still possible to avoid hardcoding the classname all over the place in the code by using `self.__class__` in its place. If that's too long, a local variable can be created at the beginning of the method with `cls = self.__class__` and used within instead.

Answer (score 3):

Prefer using `self.__class__.variable` - unless you want the same variable to be shared by all subclasses.

In code like this:

```
class Ant:
    count = 0
```

the "count" value is stored in the class' `__dict__` attribute. 
If you do something like:

```
class Ant:
    count = 0
    def __init__(self):
         print(self.count)
```

The attrobute access mechanism defined in Python's Data Model will see there is no instance of `count` in the instance "self", and retrieve the value from its class. So, if you are *reading*  a value from a class variable, you can use it jus tlike a normal instance.

However, if your code goes like:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.count += 1
```

What happens ins an entire different things: Python *Reads*  the attribute from the class as above, adds 1 to it, and stores the new result in the instance.

So, whenever you want to access the class value, you can either hard-code the class name - (since when the method code is run, the class is already created and is "known"):

```
class Ant:
    count = 0
    def __init__(self):
         Ant.count += 1
```

Or, better yet, use the instance's `__class__` attribute - that way you will always get the variable value for the proper subclass

```
class Ant:
     count = 0
     def __init__(self):
         self.__class__.count += 1

class FireAnt(Ant):
     count = 0
```

(Note that,  like in the second example above, if the subclass contains no own `count` variable, the value from the superclass' `count` will be read, a new one will be created on the subclass the first time this code is run)